# PFQueryTableViewController cell crashes after loading some data

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am working on PFQueryTableViewController to upload data. Everything is working fine but after loading 50-60 rows, app crashes and I get this error: "[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x34a53830." This is my piece of code.

```
@implementation ScreenUsersViewController

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
self = [super initWithCoder:aCoder];
if (self) {
    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.parseClassName = @"_User";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.textKey = @"name";

    self.imageKey=@"profilePicture";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 10;
   }
return self;
 }

 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [super viewDidLoad];
 [self loadObjects];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
 }

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable
 {
 PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
 if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
  query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
  }
 [query orderByDescending:@"name"];
 return query;
  }

 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView   cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
  {
 static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"UsersCell";

 UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView    dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
 if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]    initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
 }

// Configure the cell

PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"profilePicture"];
UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
UILabel *usedLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
UILabel *namecountry=(UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
UILabel *namestatus=(UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:104];
PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];


if (tableView == self.tableView)
{   
thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb_profile_default.jpg"];

nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"username"];

usedLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"Label1"];

[namecountry setText:_country];

namestatus.text = [object objectForKey:@"Status"];

[thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error)   {
        thumbnailImageView.image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];
         }];

 }

else if(tableView == self.searchController.searchResultsTableView)
 {
    PFObject *searchedUser = [self.usersFilteredResult  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *content = [searchedUser objectForKey:@"username"];

    nameLabel.text = content;
    thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fb_profile_default.jpg"];

    PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"profilePicture"];

    [thumbnail getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        thumbnailImageView.image =[UIImage imageWithData:data];
    }];
    NSLog(@"Content: %@", content);  
}
return cell;
}
```

Comment: One of the objects you are using looks to be the `[NSNull null]` instance. You or something you are calling is then trying to call `rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]` which does not exist for an `NSNull` instance. What is the stack trace in the console when it crashes?

Comment: error: (null)
2015-05-04 18:57:20.251 Laybls development[3176:492593] -[NSNull rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x34a53830
(lldb). All objects are there. Even, I tried to remove some data, but it still crashes at exactly same point.

Comment: There should be a stack trace after the error in the console?

Comment: You also have 2 thumbnail variables: One declared and assigned at the start and a second one assigned the same way in the else statement. Probably not causing your issue though.

Comment: You should also be using `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` and not `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`.

Comment: argc int(1) 
argv (char **)0x004f8acc
*argv=(char *) "/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/A75F68E2-C162-4B7A-9506-BC0B4BD231D0/Laybls development.app/Laybls development" 0x004f8bc8
**argv=char'/'. This is stack trace. I checked, thumbnail is not a problem. Also "dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier" is also not causing the problem.

Comment: You need to try and find where it is crashing. Put lots of NSLog statements in and print out values of the objects and their contents as you go. You should switch to the other form of `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`, since the version that takes the `indexPath` is designed for use in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.